# User input based circle drawing, then printing to paper with fixed sizes

Tags: python, math, printing, geometry

How to create a program, that places circles in a coordinate system based on user inputs (x,y, and circle diameter (mm)), and after that, the user can print the graph to a paper, which then can be used for positioning and drilling.

Now, the work flow process is this:
1-Create an Excel table with fixed mm cell steps.
2-Draw fix position and diameter circles into that table.
3-Print the excel table with the circles to a A4 paper.
4-Use the circle positions and the graph for work.

My task is to create a program, which places the circles automatically based on user input parameters, so that we can eliminate the human error factor.

My first idea was that to create a python Tkinter GUI, which does the work, then print a generated pdf from it. The problem was that Tkinter doesn't have mm/cm units, and with pixels I can't guarantee, that the printed graph will have the standard metric sizes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

def draw_circles_and_save_pdf(circle_data, filename="output.pdf"):
    # Create a figure with DPI that reflects the print size in millimeters
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(210/25.4, 297/25.4), dpi=100) # A4 size in inches: 210mm x 297mm
    ax.set_xlim(0, 210) # Assuming the coordinate system is in millimeters
    ax.set_ylim(0, 297)
    
    for x, y, diameter in circle_data:
        circle = plt.Circle((x, y), diameter/2, fill=False)
        ax.add_artist(circle)
    
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.grid(True, which='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
    plt.axis('off')

    # Save the plot to a PDF
    pp = PdfPages(filename)
    pp.savefig(fig)
    pp.close()

# Example usage
circle_data = [
    (50, 50, 20), # Each tuple is (x, y, diameter)
    (100, 150, 30),
    # Add more circles as needed
]
draw_circles_and_save_pdf(circle_data)
```

Comment: Thank you! Some more questions from me, what is that 25.4 in the dividing at the figsize? Can Matplotlib show figure-s on some tkinter GUI or something else? I see you have some skills in tasks like this, could you extend this code to be able to show the coordinate system on the pdf page (now I can only see the circles), get a basic user input for the parameters, and show some preview window before generating the pdf? I really like your solution. Thanks, Ben

Comment: hey , The 25.4 in the figsize
The value 25.4 is used to convert millimeters to inches. Since the figsize parameter in matplotlib is defined in inches, and you want your figure size to correspond to A4 paper size (which is 210mm x 297mm), you divide those values by 25.4 to convert them to inches. This is because there are exactly 25.4 millimeters in an inch.